# Angular - How to maintain on init value

Tags: angular, angular8

Here is the code.

```
@Input() tableObj: {};
defVal: any;
 
ngOnInit() {
    this.defVal = this.tableObj;
    console.log(this.defVal);
    // Getting oninit value
}
 
reset() {
    console.log(this.defVal);
    // Getting updated value here
    // Required same as onload value here.
}
```

**tableObj** is using in the UI grid where the user can modify.

I want to maintain the onload value to add the data back on reset.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that the `tableObj` is an object, the `defVal` contains a reference to it. So any changes made to `tableObj` will be reflected in `defVal`. One workaround is to create a deep clone using the following statement.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.defVal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tableObj));
  console.log(this.defVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the onInit object using

```
this.defVal = Object.assign({}, this.tableObj)
```

and use the tableObj where you need it.